# iptables not working on Ubuntu Server / Raspberry Pi 4: "Module ip_tables not found"

Tags: iptables, raspberrypi

`iptables` isn't working on Ubuntu Server 20.04 running on a Raspberry Pi 4:

```
$ sudo iptables -L
modprobe: FATAL: Module ip_tables not found in directory /lib/modules/5.4.0-1012-raspi
iptables v1.8.4 (legacy): can't initialize iptables table `filter': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
```

I have tried completely removing and re-installing `iptables`, but the same fatal error occurs.

Is this something that's broken on Ubuntu Server for Raspberry Pi?

Comment: Performed a clean installed. It's fixed now.

Comment: This appears to still be an issue as of 5.4.0-1022-raspi.

Answer (score 1):

You are not alone. I too noticed the other day when I first was setting up my pi4 with Ubuntu 20.04.
I do not have a solution for you right now, but I do know the problem.
So /lib/modules/5.4.0-1012-raspi/modules.order indicates that ip_tables should be located /lib/modules/5.4.0-1012-raspi/kernel/net/ipv4/netfilter/ip_tables.ko,
and dpkg -S /lib/modules/5.4.0-1012-raspi/kernel/net/ipv4/netfilter/ip_tables.ko tells us that the linux-modules-5.4.0-1012-raspi package should have put the package there, but obviously it is not there. In fact the whole netfilter subdir is gone.
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-modules-5.4.0-1012-raspi does not fix...
I thought I would try something dangerous since I have seriously started using my PI4 yet.

ubuntu@ubuntu:/lib/modules/5.4.0-1012-raspi$ sudo apt install --reinstall linux-modules-5.4.0-1011-raspi
sudo: unable to resolve host ubuntu: Temporary failure in name resolution
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 20 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/29.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 104789 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-modules-5.4.0-1011-raspi_5.4.0-1011.11_arm64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-modules-5.4.0-1011-raspi (5.4.0-1011.11) over (5.4.0-1011.11) ...
Setting up linux-modules-5.4.0-1011-raspi (5.4.0-1011.11) ...
Processing triggers for linux-image-5.4.0-1011-raspi (5.4.0-1011.11) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-1011-raspi
Using DTB: bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb
Installing /lib/firmware/5.4.0-1011-raspi/device-tree/broadcom/bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb into /boot/dtbs/5.4.0-1011-raspi/./bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb
Taking backup of bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb.
Installing new bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb.
Ignoring old or unknown version 5.4.0-1011-raspi (latest is 5.4.0-1012-raspi)
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-flash-kernel:
Using DTB: bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb
Installing /lib/firmware/5.4.0-1011-raspi/device-tree/broadcom/bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb into /boot/dtbs/5.4.0-1011-raspi/./bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb
Taking backup of bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb.
Installing new bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb.
Ignoring old or unknown version 5.4.0-1011-raspi (latest is 5.4.0-1012-raspi)

As you can see it bailed out using 1011 version. However I could see that there was a network subdir in 1011, and copied it over to 1012 subdir in the right place...
Unfortunately after reboot the copied network directory was wiped....So maybe some security measure removed it...

So bottom line, definately a bug in linux-modules-5.4.0-1012-raspi and hopefully fixed soon. I will see if I can file a bug myself in the next day or so, or find if one has already been submitted. But I image it should be fixed with linux-modules-5.4.0-1013-raspi whenever that comes, or if there is a fixed version of linux-modules-5.4.0-1012-raspi to come in an update.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please use the *Post answer* button only for actual answers. You should modify your original question to add additional information. This is [not a forum](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/are-stack-exchange-sites-forums). So please don't add "Me too!"s. If you have a NEW question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//askubuntu.com/questions/ask) button. If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](//askubuntu.com/privileges/vote-up) the question. Alternatively, "bookmark" it and you will be notified of any new answers.