# Raspberry Pi server image for focal missing modules needed for docker (ip_table)

Tags: 20.04, docker, raspberrypi

All:

I am unable to get docker running on the server version of Raspberry Pi for Focal Fossa. The error message from running dockerd generates FATAL message "Module ip_tables not found in directory /lib/modules/5.4.0-1012-raspi"

Details:

1. Raspberry Pi 4
2. uname -a: Linux appserver02-sea 5.4.0-1012-raspi #12-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 27 04:08:35 UTC 2020 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
3. lsb_release: Ubuntu 20.04 focal.

Note that the linux-generic kernel appears to include the modules. However, attempting to install it failed with:

> Couldn't find DTB bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb on the following paths:
> /etc/flash-kernel/dtbs /usr/lib/linux-image-5.4.0-39-generic
> /lib/firmware/5.4.0-39-generic/device-tree/ Installing  into
> /boot/dtbs/5.4.0-39-generic/./bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb

This may reflect the fact that I am running system using the SD card only for booting. System itself is on a USB drive for performance and stability reasons.

- steve

Answer (score 0):

You are not alone, this seems like similar, in fact it is exact same cause as
[iptables not working on Ubuntu Server / Raspberry Pi 4: "Module ip_tables not found"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1249452/iptables-not-working-on-ubuntu-server-raspberry-pi-4-module-ip-tables-not-fo/1254655#1254655)

I tried to post an update to my original reply (mojibake), but askubuntu was not playing nice as a guest, so back as a signed up user...

So the real cause you ask?
All the modules are in the linux-modules-5.4.0-1012-raspi package and if you force as re-install of the package(sudo apt install linux-modules-5.4.0-1012-raspi --reinstall) the ip_tables modules and a whole lot more will be available in /lib/modules/5.4.0-1012-raspi/kernel/net/ipv4/

But as soon as you reboot, poof, all gone... and you can't docker to you..

It is interesting you mention your setup, SD card for boot, and system on USB stick, that is same setup as me.

Answer (score 0):

Ding ding ding.. On to something here..
I remember reading about this could be a problem when updating stuff in `/boot` such as `vmlinux` etc...

I mounted the root partition of the SD card and copied over everything in `/boot/` except for the firmware dir which was already mounted.
However in the middle of installing the contents of `/boot/dtbs` on my USB lost the 1012 raspi sub-dir.So I ran a reinstall of **linux-modules** and copied them over right away.

I did a `sudo sync` but it lost the modules once again.Tried reinstall now that `vmlinux` should be pointing to the 1012 version of kernel.
No go.

I think the `/boot` of the SD also needs to be mounted.
It is getting late, but that is where I am at, if can figure out how to mount `/boot` of my SD card in `fstab`, should be good.
Note my `fstab` mounts using labels.Was sure to make labels of SD Card and USB stick different.

Steve I am guessing you `fstab` is similar to

```
LABEL=writable  /    ext4   defaults    0 0
LABEL=system-boot       /boot/firmware  vfat    defaults        0       1
```

Odd thing.Both those labels are my SD Card partition labels,
however `df -lh` will show that `/dev/sda2` (USB) is mounted to `/`

Still some learning to do.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I got it fixed and working. Unfortunately I don't know exactly what made the difference, but I will share my process.

- Formatted my USB drive as a BTRFS drive with two subvolumes - /@  and @home.
- Recorded the UUID of the USB disk.
- Using Raspberry Pi imager, recreated a fresh image of an Ubuntu 64 server image.
- Mounted both the SD card (two partitions "writeable" and "system-boot") and the USB drive on a second Linux system..
- Transferred the contents of the writeable partition to the @
  subvolume using the following rsync command. Note that this rsync command was different from the one I used originally. Unlike my original rsync, this one does a better job of making an exact copy( permissions, acls, symbolic links, etc). (Note: be careful with the paths in order to ensure that the copy to the BTRFS partition does not create a parent directory. This will involve adding a trailing slash to the path to the writeable directory/disk):

  ```
   rsync -avxHAX --info=progress2 <path to writable>/ <path to @>
  ```
- Modified /@/etc/fstab on the USB drive to correctly mount the root, boot and home directories (Note that I substituted the UUID of the SD card for the system-boot label)

  ```
   UUID=0468-A52F       /boot/firmware  vfat    defaults        0       1
   UUID=e2bebc64-1b17-4375-a6fe-afa02143f297   / btrfs  rw,relatime,compress=lzo,autodefrag,user_subvol_rm_allowed,subvol=@ 0 0 
   UUID=e2bebc64-1b17-4375-a6fe-afa02143f297   /home  btrfs rw,relatime,compress=lzo,,autodefrag,subvol=@home 0       0
  ```
- Updated cmdline.txt in the system-boot partition of the SD card to allow it to recognize the BTRFS structure. Here's what mine looks like:

  ```
    net.ifnames=0 dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=UUID=<USB drive UUID>  rootfstype=btrfs rootflags=subvol=@ elevator=deadline rootwait fixrtc
  ```

At this point, I was good to go - attached the SD card and the USB drive and powered on.

One last tidbit that may be of use. You can force the Pi to boot into single user mode by appending `systemd.unit=rescue.target` to the cmdline.txt. This was needed to investigate problems and because the normal keypress to control the boot process didn't work (evidently when that option is displayed, the USB keyboard is not yet available )

As I said I'm not sure what caused the problem in the first place. My top guesses would be:

1. A corrupt SD card image due to either the imager program or from mucking about with the system-boot contents.
2. An incomplete transfer of the contents of the writeable partition to my USB drive.

Good Luck,

-steve